# Missing empty suffix iterator for std::regex_token_iterator?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, iterator

I expect I'm misunderstanding the description [at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator), but could someone explain why the following code:

```
std::regex comma(",");
std::string string("one,two,");
std::sregex_token_iterator begin{ string.begin(), string.end(), comma, -1 }, end;
for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
{
    std::cout << "submatch = '" << it->str() << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

outputs just two submatches:

```
submatch = 'one'
submatch = 'two'
```

rather than also including an empty suffix iterator submatch for the empty string following the last comma?

```
submatch = ''
```

Encountered using Visual C++ 2017 and /std:c++17 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why should it have an empty suffix iterator?  There are no characters after the last `,` so there is nothing to match.  If there is nothing to match then there is nothing to not match so you don't get a suffix iterator.  If it didn't do this there there would always be a empty non match at the end.

Comment: I expect you're right, though given that the point of the suffix iterator is to return *non-matched* suffixes, it wasn't obvious to me that there not being anything to match mattered. Also, what additional matches would result (other than the one in this question)?

Comment: Also, do you know what the idiomatic way to get the 'split' behavior I was looking for is then?

Comment: Image `std::regex comma("@example.com;?"); std::string string("bob@example.com;alice@example.com");` instead of what you have.  You would get `bob` and `alice` as non matches.  If we included the empty match then the result would have three matches which wouldn't be expected.

Comment: You can use [this approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c100e4b16be7ff9) but it only works for single character delimiters.

Comment: @NathanOliver using `std::regex comma(",|$")` almost works here, except $ matches end of line as well as end of input, and I can't figure out how to change that.

Comment: PS `std::regex comma(R"(,|($(?!\s)))")` does the trick.

Comment: Cool.  You might want to write up a self answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver if the target character sequence is modified to `",one,two,"`, then we will get  tokens `"", "one", "two"` (tested with gcc v9.4.0 and `-std=c++17`). Yet under your previous argument (_"no chars after last `,`, so nothing to match"_), the 1st token here should be `"one"` (instead of `""`). Hence I think a reasonable expectation would be that **either** we get `"", "one", "two", ""` (like most splitter algorithms do) **or** `"one", "two"` (instead of a mix of these).

Comment: Using gcc v9.4.0 and ECMAScript (default grammar), `std::regex comma(",|$")` is enough to get the result intended by OP (`$` only matches the end of the string since flag `std::regex::multiline` isn't supported by gcc).